# AngularJS get value from API only if not already set

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I have service to get some data from API and serve them to application.
Simple function like this:

```
getEnvironmentStatus() {
    var _this = this;
    var req = {
        method: "GET",
        url: "/api/system/hosting",
        headers: {},
        data: {}
    }
    return _this.$http(req);
}
```

In some other place I have:

```
determineHostingEnv() {
    var _this = this;
    this.$env.getEnvironmentStatus()
    .then(function(response){
        _this.EnvHositng = response.data.cloud_hosted;
     }, function(error) {
    }); 
}
```

If I need the same information in other place (other controller), I would need to call api again.

How can I make getEnvironmentStatus() function to call API only once and store data in local variable, so it can serve that variable next time it is asked for it, instead of calling API?
Also, what if that value will get requested a few times before the first API will return value? Can I prevent calling that API a few times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can cache the promise:

```
httpPromiseCache = null;

getEnvironmentStatus() {
    var _this = this;
    var req = {
        method: "GET",
        url: "/api/system/hosting",
        headers: {},
        data: {}
    }
    if (!_this.httpPromiseCache) _this.httpPromiseCache = _this.$http(req);
    return _this.httpPromiseCache;
}
```

The service will only execute the HTTP request once.